# C# .NET Core, Accessing Active Directory in MAC OS X Cross Platform?

Tags: c#, macos, active-directory, .net-core

I am attempting a simple Active Directory user authentication on a Windows 2012 server from a MAC OS X platform.

I'm getting a System.DLLNotFoundException Unable to load shared library Kernel32.dll or one of its dependencies.

System.DirectoryServices reference is included in the project (see screen shot)

[image]

Any suggestions?  Can Active Directory in .NET Core 2.1 be used in a cross platform application like this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post images of code.

Comment: Any idea how to resolve this?  I posted the error from the mac.